# XElement.ToString( ) is including an xmlns that doesn't exist in the source

Tags: c#, xml

To preface my question, I am working with Xml content with unknown schemas at runtime.

When I have an Xml document with a default namespace, such as `xmlns="someNamespace"`, whenever I call `.ToString( )` on a child element, the `xmlns="someNamespace"` appears in the text, which I cannot allow in my case. Here's a working example to illustrate:

```
void Main()
{
    string xml ="<root xmlns=\"someNamespace\"><node>HELLO</node></root>";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    foreach(XNode node in doc.Root.Elements())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.ToString());
    }
}
```

The result of this is:

```
<node xmlns="someNamespace">HELLO</node>
```

Note the xmlns that didn't exist in the source xml. Again, I don't know the schemas at runtime, so xmlns and other attributes could actually be in the source. I just don't want to modify at all.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You are operating under a false premise, the xml has not changed, which node the default namespace is declared on has. Can't really help without knowing what this "solution" was trying to achieve. Personally I'd say you were stuffed without adding the namespaces from the original to the document you are trying to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `node` element is a child of `root` it inherits the namespace declarations of `root`.  To interpret `node` in the proper context it must include the namespace declaration of the parent when emitted independently of the parent.  Otherwise the names would potentially have a different meaning than they did in the original declaration

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand it inherits the namespace, what I'm looking to do is extract/display an element such as `node` exactly as it appears in the original text.

Comment: @KTJT in order to do that I think you're going to have to write your own function.  By default the ToString of XNode is going to force this behavior.  I'm not aware of an API in XLINQ which provides the type of output you are looking for

Comment: @KTJT if you're asking for code, this isn't the place. Try it on your own, and when it doesn't work, come here.

Comment: @JaredPar I was afraid this was the correct answer. I'll mark it as such after a while if I don't get an actual solution.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Believe me, I've tried it every which way. So I came here. I'm not looking for a custom method that's iterating over the angle brackets, I'm looking for some way to get System.Xml.Linq to do my bidding.

Comment: @KTJT that's great, but Stack Overflow requires _evidence_ of effort. Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer but long comment... JaredPar answer is the same and shorter.*

`ToString` and all combinations of inner/outer XML or use of normal `XmlWriter` will produce XML equivalent (from XML point of view) to original one. In your case it means (as JaredPar pointed out) default namespace declaration is moved down to child node when that node serialized alone.

Since you want to create XML that is not equivalent to original one (due to different namespaces) you have to manually clone nodes (probably all of them) into default namespace. Note that you will likely lose order of attributes from source text and have to be very careful with whitespaces.

Another options would be to write custom `XmlWriter` that ignores namespace prefixes or use XSLT to do copy transform.

Note: prefixes (including empty one) make sense only in context of parent node. Tearing child node and not carrying over prefixes declaration changes meaning of the document.

```
<r xmlns="urn:u1">
   <c xmlns="urn:u2">
      <d/>
   <c/>
<r/>
```